# running specific target in different ant scripts in different directories

Tags: ant, subant

We have a large amount of apps. They all have a `build.xml` file located in the projects base directory. I am trying to create an ant script that will go through and call a specific target on each of the `build.xml` files in all the projects.

Here are the issues:

1. Some of the projects are in deeper directories than others.
2. Only some of the projects need to be built at a time.

I was trying to use `subant` + `antfile` and defining a CSV of file paths in a properties file, but this did not work. Below is what i have and the error i am getting.

If there is a better way to do this or you know what my problem is, please let me know! Thanks!

This is the property defined in a property file. I am wanting the person running the script to add the file paths in here that are relative to the current location of the script they are running.

```
projects.to.build=
```

---

This is the subant task i am trying to use in the main build script.

```
    <filelist
        id="projectNames"
        dir="${basedir}"
        files="${projects.to.build}"
    />

    <target name="debugAll" description="Builds all the projects listed in the projectNames.properties file.">
        <subant target="debug" antfile="${projects.to.build}">
        </subant>
    </target>
```

---

Here is the error i get when i try to run the build script when there are projects defined in the properties file. I am using the relative path. For example: ..\Apps\AnApp1\build.xml,..\Apps\AnApp2\build.xml,..\OtherApps\foo\AnotherApp1\build.xml

```
"No Build Path Specified" (at my subant task)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You specified the **antfile** attribute, so ANT was expecting to a single **build.xml** file.

---

The [subant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) describes how you can use a fileset as child parameter.

Here's an example:

```
<project name="Subant demo" default="run-debug-target">
    <target name="run-debug-target">
        <subant target="debug">
            <fileset dir="." includes="**/build.xml" excludes="build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

## Update

Alternatively a [filelist](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) could be used:

```
<project name="Dry run" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <subant target="test">
            <filelist dir="projects" files="one/build.xml,two/build.xml,three/build.xml,four/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

Processing the following build files:

- projects/one/build.xml
- projects/two/build.xml
- projects/three/build.xml
- projects/four/build.xml

Comment: Yeah, but i want to be able to specify which projects to build by reading in a property set in a properties file. I would like this property to be a CSV of relative paths to a projects build file. And the only way i found that i could do that would be to use `filelist` and the only example i found with `filelist` was with antfile. Is there a way to achieve my goal with `fileset`?

Comment: @prolink007 I've updated my post with a filelist, as requested. You can easily use a property to to hold the list of CSV formatted file names

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the help! I was trying to over complicate things. =(

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to run the target in the all the build files concurrently ?

E.g.

```
<project name="Dry run" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <subant target="test">
            <filelist dir="projects" files="one/build.xml,two/build.xml,three/build.xml,four/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

In this example, is there any way to run target "test" present in all the build files (one/build.xml,two/build.xml,three/build.xml,four/build.xml) concurrently ?

Comment: You will be more likely to get a response for that if you ask it as a question.