# Move a ant dir project after the ant or subant task completes

Tags: ant

Currently i'm using a shell script to do the following:

```
cd myproject1/
ant
cd ..
if grep 'sucessful' myproject/buil.log then move myproject ../backup/today/
```

And so on for myproject2, myproject3.

If some error happens, the project stay in the current dir to be reprocessed but the whole process continues.

I want to migrate this process to an ant build script but i have no clue on how to do this.

I have looked at ant and subant tasks. Ant looks more suitable to the job but i can't find a way to loop through a directory list using ant and move task togheter, checking if the ant task completes or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this answer:

[running specific target in different ant scripts in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132766/running-specific-target-in-different-ant-scripts-in-different-directories/9140052#9140052)

I recommend that your submodule builds should throw an error rather than try and duplicate the log parsing logic.

## Update

If this is designed to support deployment, perhaps you should consider a groovy script?
Would better support exception conditions:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

scanner = ant.fileScanner {
    fileset(dir:".", includes:"test*/build.xml")
}

scanner.each { f ->
    try {
        ant.ant(antfile:f)
    }
    catch (e) {
        ant.mkdir(dir:"backup")
        ant.move(todir:"backup", file:f.parent) 
    }
}
```

Groovy has excellent ANT integration and can also be embedded within your ANT build:

```
<target name="run">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <fileset id="buildFiles" dir="." includes="test*/build.xml"/>

    <groovy>
        project.references.buildFiles.each { 
            def f = new File(it.toString())
            try {
                ant.ant(antfile:f)
            }
            catch(e) {
                ant.mkdir(dir:"backup")
                ant.move(todir:"backup", file:f.parent) 
            }
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. But based on your example (as well as the ant docs examples) i can't move the dir to a backup dir for each ant execution, only at the end of the process.

Comment: @GiulianiSanches Just trying to understand your requirements: Why do you need to move the directories at all? Normally build files are held under revision control. Using this, an automated build server (Like Jenkins) can then manage a dedicated workspace for each build job.

Comment: Just as a matter of organization. It's a build script that deploy some BPEL process to the production environment. Keeping only the faluted process in the directory make things more easy to the operation area to analyse and report the problems. (also, is a customer requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may be what you're looking for :

```
<target name="compile" >

    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${class.dir}" />

</target >

<target name="copy" depends="compile" >

    <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}" />

    <copy todir="${dest.dir}" overwrite="true">

        <fileset dir="${class.dir}" includes="**" />

        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**" />

        ...

   </copy>

</target>
```

Comment: Looks like i do not have a way to move the dir after process it. I need to wait for the entire process to finish to move all the dirs in one operation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'entire process' ? Can you maybe share relevant parts of your current build.xml ?

Comment: This is the piece of shell script that i want to convert to an ant build.xml: http://pastebin.com/etJxNPfL. Thank you for your help.