# How to call "jar", "war" targets of subprojects in an integrated build file?

Tags: ant

I want to create an integrated ant
build file for my project. My project
has 5 subprojects. Now I've to call
"jar" and "war" targets of these
subprojects. How do I call these
targets in the integrated build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ant antfile="../subproject/build.xml" target="jar" />
```

That will do it for you.  If you want to pass properties from the parent to the sub-projects simply set inheritAll="true" (defaults to true) but it is sometime helpful to set that to false if you find that things are misbehaving.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

Answer (score 2):

The `subant` task is dedicated to that kind of sub project build.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html

Comment: Subant is the way to go. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132766/running-specific-target-in-different-ant-scripts-in-different-directories/9140052#9140052

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'import' or 'include' tag to integrate your subtasks. Check for more info this https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.htm or this https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html. Also, they support 'as' parameter, which is very useful in complex builds.